# How to remove 0s and 1s from my JSON obj

Tags: javascript, php, json

This is my code :

```
...
$response = mysqli_fetch_all($result);
$json = json_encode($response);

echo json_encode($json);
...
```

and it returns some kind of JSON like this:

```
"{0: mystring :D, 1: myotherstring :(}"
```

How can I remove those 0s and 1s? I know I didn't explain well, but it is actually hard for me to explain :(... Thanks in advance :)

Comment: if from javascript `delete json['0']; delete json['1'];`

Comment: You are using `json_encode` twice. This should definitely cause problems.

Comment: You're doing a fetch call which returns a dual-keyed array: numeric + string. Since JS arrays cannot have non-numeric keys, you're getting an object instead. Change how you fetch from the result handle, or live with the extra keys in your data.

Comment: Is there any way I can slap them off the JSON?

Comment: You need to add the `MYSQLI_ASSOC`to the `mysqli_fetch_all()` call, I think. (Haven't worked this low-level stuff in a while.)

Comment: You should be able to use json_encode(array_values($response)).http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php

Comment: I got it it was me being silly..... I didnt see I had a loop to show the JSON content which showed the keys or, 0, 1, ect lol thanks for ur help!

Comment: `$response = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);` should keep you from having the numeric keys to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "0"s and "1"s are the keys in your JSON object; if you want to remove them, it seems an array would suit your need better. You could convert it with the following and end up with an array which only contains the values:

```js
var json = {"0":"foo","1":"bar"};
var array = [];

for (var x in json) {
  array.push(json[x]);
}
```